# Is there an algorithm to solve line intersections of meshes?

Tags: algorithm, mesh-network

I've got the mesh below, is there any algorithm which can rearrange the points so the lines don't overlap anymore?

[image]

Comment: You're looking for a planar embedding, several libraries out there, e.g., https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/graph/doc/planar_graphs.html

Answer (score -3):

No, if the graph is non-planar.

Comment: Consider adding some relevant info or convert your answer into a comment.

Comment: https://www.javatpoint.com/planar-and-non-planar-graphs#:~:text=Non%2DPlanar%20Graph%3A,they%20are%20non%2Dplanar%20graphs.

Comment: @MarkLavin I don't think I agree with you. Consider moving the second-uppermost vertex.

Comment: @Berthur yes, moving that vertex to the right, passing over two lines solves it